# Provide extra condition in eager loading which includes comparing of two columns, laravel

Tags: laravel, relationships

I have tables students, profiles, subjects and pivot table profile_subject

-students---------{id,profile_id,year}

-profiles---------{id}

-profile_subject--{profile_id,subject_id,year}

-subjects---------{id}

I want to select a student with id 5, and eager load profile and subjects for the students year.

Something like this:

```
$student = Student::with('profile','profile.subjects')->find(5);
```

But I also have to insert the condition

```
->wherePivot('year','=','students.year')
```

there somewhere. How to do that?
This query will not do the job cos it will search for records which year is "students.year" literary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading). This code will not create any additional queries, it'll create the same amount of queries as `with()` would:

```
$student = Student::find(5);
$sudent->load(['profile', 'profile.subjects' => function ($q) use ($student) {
    $q->wherePivot('year', $student->year);
}]);
```

Comment: Hm, great if it works! And if I need it for all the students just to loop it through foreach?

Comment: Yes, but since it's nested relationship foreach syntax will be a bit different for different types of relationships.

Comment: So great, thanks! :) Very powerful this lazy eager, it's strange they didn't emphasize it a bit, I am about to use it frequently